# Python como imprimir saida

Tags: python, python-3.x

Como posso imprimir uma lista dessa forma, exemplo:

```
l=[4,26,32]
```

Quero imprimir a saída da seguinte forma:

```
4 26 32
```

Sem vírgula e com um espaço em branco na mesma linha.
Grato desde já.

Comment: Este é seu dever de casa?

Answer (score 8):

Utilize o método [join](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html) e o [map](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map). Isto também tem a vantagem de ser portável entre as versões *Python 2.x e 3.x*.

Veja o exemplo:

```
l=[4,26,32]

print(' '.join(map(str, l)))
```

Saída:

> 4 26 32

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13550423/python-printing-without-commas

Comment: Obrigado,é de grande ajuda.

Comment: A quem deu -1, se tiver algo que eu possa melhorar na resposta, por favor deixe um comentário.

Answer (score 2):

Existe algumas formas para você resolver esta questão.

**1ª forma de resolução:**

Nesta forma você implementa um laço **for**, itera sobre a lista **l** e exibe cada elemento da lista com o auxílio de `end=' '`.

```
l = [4, 26, 32]

for c in l:
    print(c, end=' ')
print()
```

**2ª forma de resolução:**

```
l = [4, 26, 32]
print(*l)
```

Answer (score 1):

Esta é simples!

```
print (str(l[0]) + ' ' + str(l[1]) + ' ' + str(l[2]))
```

Tratando em lista:

```
for i in l:
   print (str(i) + ' ', end="");
```

Comment: Usei três números como exemplo,mas e se caso fossem 20 ou 30 números,como fazer?

Comment: Algo que vale-se para qualquer quantidade de elementos da lista.

Comment: Editei a resposta.

Comment: Muito obrigado,é de grande ajuda!

Comment: Quando uma resposta o satisfaz, dá uma votação +1 na resposta!

Answer (score 0):

É possível percorrer uma lista em Python utilizando a estrutura de repetição `For N in L:` ou seja `Percorra todas as posições da minha lista e me retorne N`, depois disso é só realizar um output de `N` dentro da estrutura de repetição.

Aconselho essa [vídeo aula](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cL4YDtFnCt4) se quiser aprender um pouco mais sobre `For`.

Comment: Embora este link possa responder à pergunta, é melhor incluir as partes essenciais da resposta aqui e fornecer o link para referência.  As respostas apenas por link podem ser invalidadas se a página com o link for alterada. - [Da Revisão](/review/low-quality-posts/295364)

Comment: @gmsantos bem, acredito que as partes essenciais para a resposta foram citadas já que não é algo muito complexo de ser transcrevido, pelo visto o autor da pergunta é uma pessoa que está iniciando na programação e precisa aprender a transcrever as coisas para o código, assim como é no mercado de trabalho, fiz o que gostaria que fizesse comigo caso eu tivesse iniciando por agora.

Answer (score -3):

```
letrers = None    
for element in i:    
    letrers += f'{element} '  
print(letrers)
```

Comment: Poderia complementar a resposta explicando-a?

Comment: Bem vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português. Esse código pode ser uma solução para a pergunta, mas sua resposta pode ser melhor se você incluir uma explicação sobre os principais pontos do código. O objetivo não é ajudar apenas quem fez a pergunta, mas os próximos visitantes também. Leia mais em [Respostas apenas com código - O que fazer?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/7172/100416).